# Gnome icons pack

Tags: linux, graphics, user-interface, icons, gnome

Does anyone know where can i find this icon set for download (pngs + svgs)
http://www.iconspedia.com/search/gnome/0/

and also, is the icons license allows it to be used in commercial applications?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is tango project artwork

You can check everything you want to know about it on it's project website: http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project

Comment: I just downloaded Tango. Tango is 215 icons. the set on the site is 300 icons. i need the one on the site :/

Comment: It's not Tango. GNOME icon pack *follows* the Tango guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have the SVGs, but it does have all the PNGs. Download link is at the [bottom:http://www.iconspedia.com/pack/gnome-desktop-2042/#dload_ip](http://www.iconspedia.com/pack/gnome-desktop-2042/#dload_ip)

Answer (score 0):

> and also, is the icons license allows
>   it to be used in commercial
>   applications?

As long as you comply with the GPL.

Where to get them? Download your favorite GNOME desktop distro and the icons will be in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable` all in SVG format.

EDIT: There you go - a [download](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gnome-icon-theme/2.28/) link.